# Referência circular entre dois projetos

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou trabalhando com dois projetos em uma *solution*.

Pra usar um form do **ProjetoA** no **ProjetoB** eu fiz referência do **ProjetoA** no **ProjetoB**, a partir disso tenho acesso aos forms do **ProjetoA**.

Mas e se eu quiser ter acessos ao forms do **ProjetoB** no **ProjetoA**?

Como eu faço? Visto que não permite fazer referencia do B no A já que já foi feito uma referencia do **A** no **B**.

Comment: Se você quis dizer "ProjetoB no ProjetoA" ao invés de "ProjetoB no ProjetoB", isso não é possível pois causaria circular referencia.

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo que acusa, não tem nenhuma forma de acessar o projetoB no projetoA?

Comment: Da maneira que estás fazendo é impossível.

Comment: Uma possível solução caso isso seja necessário para sua solução é criar um terceiro projeto base, onde terá todos os Forms que são comuns entre ProjetoB e ProjetoA e fazer com que o o ProjetoB e ProjetoA façam referencia ao ProjetoBase. assim os 2 projetos tem acesso aos Forms comuns entre eles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da forma que você está pensando, causará uma **referência circular**, logo, você não vai conseguir fazer isso.

## Solução

Sem mais detalhes sobre as regras e do porquê que precisas dividir o projeto em "duas partes" fica meio complicado de pensar numa solução prática e que se encaixe nas necessidades do seu projeto. Num primeiro momento e com as poucas informações que colocaste na pergunta, consigo pensar em duas formas de resolver isso.

#### 1. Deixar tudo apenas num projeto

Afinal, se você precisa usar os forms do **ProjetoA** no **ProjetoB** e vice-versa, por que você se preocuparia em deixá-los em projetos separados? Talvez haja alguma regra para isso, mas como não foi dito na pergunta, podemos assumir que manter tudo num mesmo projeto é uma ideia melhor do que a atual.

#### 2. Criar um projeto base e referenciar os dois projetos

Neste caso, você criaria um terceiro projeto e adicionaria referências dos outros dois. Não tem muito mistério, mas pode ser que isso seja um trabalho desnecessário e usar a primeira abordagem seja uma ideia bem melhor.

Comment: Obrigado, com certeza essa é a melhor forma!

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução caso isso seja necessário para sua solução é modificar a estrutura de seus projetos.

Criando um terceiro projeto `ProjetoBase`, para onde você passará todos os `Forms` que são comuns entre `ProjetoB` e `ProjetoA` e fazer com que o `ProjetoB` e `ProjetoA` façam referência ao `ProjetoBase`. Assim os 2 projetos tem acesso aos Forms comuns entre eles.

Podemos ilustar essa relação da seguinte forma:

- `ProjetoBase` (Para Forms e recursos comuns entre os projetos)

  - `FormBase1`
  - `FormBase2`
  - `FormBase3`
  - `FormBase4`
- `ProjetoA`

  - `References`

    - `ProjetoBase` (o que da acesso aos form do ProjetoBase)
  - `FormA`
  - ... Demais forms especificos ...
- `ProjetoB`

  - `References`

    - `ProjetoBase` (o que da acesso aos form do ProjetoBase)
  - `FormB`
  - ... Demais forms especificos ...