# Não consigo fazer uma referencia a um projeto

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc

Olá, estou com uma solution em MVC divididos em 4 projetos: Model, Persistence, Contoller e View

Persistence tem uma referencia para Model

Controller tem 2 referencias para Model e Persistence

Estou tentando colocar para View uma referencia para Controller porém o Visual Studio diz que é uma referência circular,mas não compreendo o por quê

Comment: Acho que esse post aqui esse post aqui pode te ajudar:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123121/refer%C3%AAncia-circular-entre-dois-projetos

Comment: Obrigado! Muito bem explicado. Ajudou muito.